# What is the prototype for a function that takes in reference to a vector

Tags: c++

say we have this function `void sorter(vector<int> &nums)`. is its prototype `void sorter(&vector<int>)` or `void sorter(vector<int> &)`

Comment: What happens if you try each - which one works?

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was the problem in my code. After trying, the actual solution is "void sorter(vector<int> &);". It seems weird especially to me, a new c++ programmer, because of the dangling &. But it actually works

Comment: Opinion: I leave the parameter names in the prototypes. Sometimes a good variable name is all the documentation you need or get.

Comment: The best way to ask a question like this is to state what you think the answer is and provide your reasoning.  Do this and often you won't have to ask the question because the question writing process winds up answering the question (the sign of a good question-asking process). And If you still have to ask the question, we know where you're coming from and don't have to repeat work you've already performed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like how you take reference to an int.

`void sorter(int &a);` or

`void sorter(int &);`

you take a reference to a vector.

`void sorter(vector<int> &b);` or

`void sorter(vector<int> &);`